# What is meaning of the word "あっちっち"?

Tags: meaning

Sentence:

1. もぐらさんのまちは あっちっち。なぜか しゃわーがとまってる ぬーぼー たすけて。
2. あっちっち！このお風呂、熱くて入れないよ。

Context: https://youtu.be/6wAq1BfC_P0?t=772 ; https://tatoeba.org/eng/sentences/show/234336

Comment: If you can, [please give some more context](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2189/what-should-i-do-if-i-was-asked-for-the-context-why-is-it-important).

Comment: Added context and in the question too - https://youtu.be/6wAq1BfC_P0?t=772

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think given what you've included in the question it's safe to say in both cases 「あっちっち」 is an informal and colloquialized form of 「あつい」, rendered with kanji either as「暑い{あつい}」or「熱い{あつい}」depending on the context. The reason I asked you to tell us where you saw those sentences is because more context helps determine which word(s) is(are) used in the sentences.

In sentence 1「あっちっち」comes from 「暑い{あつい}」indicating hot temperature. The mole (もぐら) is trying to take a shower to cool down but the shower doesn't work. That's why it says "たすけて"/"Help!"

In sentence 2 it is「熱い{あつい}」, meaning something is hot. The bathwater is too hot to enter.